# rsync, cygwin and shell file windows

Tags: windows, shell, cygwin, rsync

Using Cygwin I can use rysnc as expected, but using the same rysnc command from a shell file I see:

> 'rsync: command not found'

Script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Moving local media to dev server'
rysnc -vruz --progress -chmod=0755 --exclude catalog/product/cache media user@domain:/var/sites/folder/folder
```

execution:

```
$ ./script.sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typo to me. Change `rysnc` to `rsync`.

PS: Don't type in error messages. Cut and paste them. Each and every character is important to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps cygwin is not installed on your machine. Install it from the Cygwin `setup.exe` that can be downloaded on www.cygwin.com